# log4j logs into different files for same package based on where it was called from

Tags: java, log4j

lets say my project has 3 packages and I am using log4j for logging.
org.a, org.b, org.c where org.c has some utils code which classes in package 'a' and package 'b' calls.

If I configure logs from org.a to go to file1 and from org.b to go to file2. I would like the logs from package 'c' to go into file1 if the caller of 'c' was some class in 'org.a' and into file2 if the caller of 'c' was some class in 'org.b'.

Please let me know if there is any configuration based or programmatic way to do this.

**Underlying Main Problem :**

I am working on [apache ambari](https://github.com/apache/ambari) project where [views](https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/trunk/contrib/views) are deployed as jar/war files. Each view defines a unique package name and all its code is inside that package. Ambari project just loads these jars/wars using separate class loaders. But log4j is instantiated by main Ambari project. I have configured separate [log files for each view](https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/contrib/views/hive/src/main/resources/view.log4j.properties) based on their package and [loaded them dynamically](https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/java/org/apache/ambari/server/view/ViewRegistry.java#L1650) using PropertyConfigurator. The problem is currently the logs from common packages like [/contrib/views/commons](https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/trunk/contrib/views/commons) goes into [Ambari's log file](https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/src/main/conf/log4j.properties) and not in individual view's log file. If I would configure it based on package name then all the logs from these package will go into any one of the view's log file and not based on caller view.

Answer (score 0):

What if you Print Caller Information in log file of common module?

Comment: Yeah that can be considered as an alternate. Any elegant way to do it?

Comment: Use  %C or %class in Log Pattern. See "Patterns" section at https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

Comment: No, the %C is the class in which the log is written. I want to print the class in which the method call is written. Ex :
class A{
someMethod (){
 B b = new B();
 b.anotherMethod();
}
}

class B{
 anotherMethod(){
  LOG.info("another method called.");
 }
}



logfile.log
B : caller-A.someMethod : another method called.